# Webstorm live edit не реагирует на изменение внешнего css

Tags: css, webstorm

При дебаге, страница реагирует только на изменение в html файле. Можно ли как нибудь настроить ide так чтобы она читала подключенные стили в live режиме?

Скрин настроек: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myrhm.jpg

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, скриншот странички *Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте включить опцию **On chahges** в **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit**. При изменении HTML, равно как и CSS/JS внутри `<style>`/`<script>` тегов, страничка перегружается всегда. Но для того, чтобы работал hotswap для внешних `.css` и `.js` файлов, нужно включить **On chahges**.

См [документацию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/live-edit.html):

```
Select this checkbox to enable Live Edit in JavaScript in addition to HTML and CSS. Set the elapsed time for applying the changes to a running application: accept the default value 300 ms or specify a custom value using the spin box next to the field. The default elapsed time is 300ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

Поставил галачку на On changes in, все прекрасно заработало.